# Google Scripts Timed-based trigger failing 100% with no error reason for some users not others

Tags: google-apps-script, timer

I have a web-app script project that is configured to be runnable as any user with a Google account and to run as that user.

The project presents a web page that has a button that sets up a time-based trigger that runs every day between midnight and 1am (it adds tasks to a task list in that user's google tasks). The button ALSO runs that function to initialize things, so I know the function works for every user when run from the UI.

The function to be run has Logger log statements in it - so any failure that is within the function can be seen in the log for that failure when viewing executions through the project console.

When first accessing the link, the user is presented with the usual "Unverified script" flow that allows the user to grant permissions necessary for the project - "execution while you are not there" and "manage tasks".

My problem is that for some users this works fine - the trigger function runs every night doing what it should.

For others, however, I get a 100% failure rate with an execution time of 0 seconds and no error messages or report emails or what-have-you at all.

I then set up a tester web-app project that, when accessed, simply sets up (or replaces) a trigger that runs every 15 minutes, eliminating all the peripheral fluff of the main app. I accessed this (with the usual "unverified" flow) from a test account that I know fails with the main app. Again, the trigger gets set up fine, but execution fails every time with no error reports or console output.

Code of the tester web-app can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/bassmanitram/20daa3627d78d5d0b3eb91572efdccd9)

How on EARTH do I debug that?

Comment: Can you share ANY code? - and no errors using `Logger.log()`?

Comment: Perhaps try/catch

Comment: Yeah, code might help - GIST  link added to the question body

Comment: The first thing in the time event function is a Logger.log call. The whole function body is encapsulated in try/catch. There is no log output whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

I'm PRETTY sure this is NOT how it's *supposed* to work, but this change makes it work.

It's a project setting! It turns out that all users can have access to your scripts interactively without granting viewer access to the project itself, but timer triggers appear to require viewer access to the project.

I.e. like this ...

[image: Restricted project access]

... the timer will fail, but like *this* ...

[image: Link project access]

... the timer will work.